# How to use Backbone's trigger method

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have this Backbone App where users and admins can log in and out. Now admins do have multiple options to add features on different pages, so for that, I have an admin-menu which should only display the relevant buttons on the relevant page. I want to use the `trigger`-method but cant get it working properly. So lets say, admins should have the possibility to change something on the frontpage, so a specific button should be visible, only on when navigating to the frontpage. This is what I did so far:

Router.js:

```
routes: {
    '': 'index',
    'home': 'home'
}

home: function(){
  App.trigger('showFrontBtn');
}
```

Then on my Admin-MenuView.js:

```
Admin-Menu.View = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div',
    template: 'adminMneu',
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
        App.on('showFrontBtn', this.changeFront, this);             
    },

    changeFront:function(user){
        alert('works!')
        if(user && user.role === 'admin'){
            $('.frontBtn').show();
        } else {
            $('.frontBtn').hide();
        }
    },
```

The thing is, that it actually returns the `alert('works')`, so I assume there must be an issue with the if statement, BUT am I using the method correctly?

Comment: *"The thing is, that I actually become the alert"* - You became what..?!

Comment: `alert('works')` - I will modify the text

Comment: `Admin-Menu.View` is a valid variable name..?

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question

Comment: That's a syntax error, none of the code you provided will work. *This is what I did so far* sounds like you've something that works *so far*, which we can work with. So Unless we're supposed to fix all such issues (*in other words create your `App` from scratch*), it has to do with the question...

Comment: Ok this was just a snippet to explain the basic idea... besides my main topic, I was asking "am I using the method correctly?" - thats all... The answer provided by Henry Zou was perfect for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `changeFront:function(user)` is expecting a "user" object passed into it.  But when you triggered the event, you didn't specify the parameter to pass (*user*).

I am guessing when you tried to access "user.role" it threw an exception because user is null and you are trying to get to null.role.

You might be confusing the third argument of the event listener with the parameter of the function. The third parameter of the app.on is actually the context not the parameter. The parameter needs to be passed by the trigger. So you can do something like

```
home: function(){
  App.trigger('showFrontBtn', {role: "Admin"});
}
```